# Android Google Signin using work profile email

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I made Google Signin in my React Native App.

Was able to do so, until recently my organization enabled work profile on Android, after which I have two versions of work Apps on my phone (Gmail, Calendar, Drive etc.) one with a personal profile and another one with work profile.

Now, I am unable to login to my App using my work email.
Please suggest the changes I need to make my App login via work emails. Can't find any resources. (Any change in manifest or in Play Store before publishing!?)

Comment: can u update your question with logs and error you are getting while login using work email?

Comment: There are no errors, I just can't see work profile email in the list of emails while signing in